# How do you call an async method when the user is typing in a textbox (oninput)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I want to call an async method every time a change is made to a textbox.

I been looking at this for a while now googling and trying the syntax I find.  The below code seems like the most accurate.

**Razor Page Code:**

```
    <div class="offset-sm-5 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" @oninput="@(async () => await OnSearchAsync())"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
    public class ListBase: ComponentBase
    {
        [Inject]
        public IVpbDelegateAdminService VpbDelegateAdminService { get; set; }

        protected VpbDelegateListVm VpbDelegateListVm { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            VpbDelegateListVm  = await VpbDelegateAdminService.GetVpbDelegateListVmAsync(1);
        }

        protected async Task OnSearchAsync()
        {
            VpbDelegateListVm = await VpbDelegateAdminService.GetVpbDelegateListVmAsync(2);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note: This is for a Blazor app.

Comment: Your code is fine. If you have another issue, please create a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to call a method from your code behind?

If that's the case, this should work.

```
 <div class="offset-sm-5 col-sm-3">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" @oninput="@OnSearchAsync"/>
        </div>
    </div>

@code
{
    private async Task OnSearchAsync()
    {
        var data = await GetYourData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have a code behind file which inherits from ComponentBase. (see above).  The call to OnInitializedAsync() works fine. I tried your changes.  Still didn't work.  The processing will not go into the method.

Comment: I just reviewed the Developer Tools. Getting the following error: blazor.server.js:15 [2020-03-27T14:57:50.459Z] Error: System.FormatException: Cannot add value because header 'Authorization' does not support multiple values.
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(HeaderDescriptor descriptor, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value) which does not make sense since the first call to my method works fine.  Let me investigate futher.

Comment: You change worked. I had a break point down API so I assume the event was not working. Once I added the breakpoint in the event. I saw it was working. Now I have to figure out why I am getting an authority error.

Comment: Yes, it works now.  The problem was authority, which I fixed.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is

```
@page "/Demo_domtree_input_typing"

@{ BlazorSession.Current["codename"] = "Demo_domtree_input_typing"; }

Your message :
<BlazorDomTree @ref="dt"></BlazorDomTree>

@code{

    BlazorDomTree dt;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool first)
    {
        if (!first)
            return;

        PlusControl inp1 = dt.Root.Create("input type='text'");
        inp1.OnChanging(delegate
        {
            BlazorSession.Current.Toast("Your are typing '" + inp1.Value + "'", 1000, "typinginfo");
        });
    }
}
```

Online live demo :
http://demo.blazorplus.com/Demo_domtree_input_typing

(It require import and setup the nuget package 'BlazorPlus')